# How to sort mysql result by select menu

Tags: php, mysql, web, web-deployment

I am working on a project where i have to display data from the mysql which i have done successfully but now i need to sort the result based on high views, low views, newly added and old, all this options using select dropdown menu.

**Html file**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" >                
    <select name="q">                
        <option value="DESC" name="DESC">High views</option>    
        <option value="ASC" name="ASC">Low views</option>                   
    </select>                        
</form>
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "movie_db";
    $q = $_Post['q'];

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT `title`, `poster`, `descrip`, `movie` ,`Duration`, `views`,`director` FROM `movie_db` ORDER BY `views` ".$q ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<p1>";
     // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        echo " <div class=\"imgc\"><a href=".$row["movie"]."><img src =" . $row["poster"]. "></a></div></p1><p2><b><a href=" .$row["movie"].">" . $row["title"]. "</a></b></p2><br><p3><b>Duration : </b>".$row["Duration"]." Mins</p3> &nbsp; <p3><b> Views : </b> ".$row["views"]."</p3><br><div><p3><b>Description :</b>".$row["descrip"]."</p3></div><br><p5> By ".$row["director"]."</p5><br>";


    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?> 

</div>
```

Php and html are in the same file that is index.php

Comment: how are you submitting the form??

Answer (score 1):

```
 $q = $_GET['q'];
        ^
```

Compare that with

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" > 
                                 ^
```

And you will `GET` your answer yourself.

Comment: i did not understand what you said

Comment: You are POSTing the form. So you should pick up the values from `$_POST`, not `$_GET`

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you have to submit that form? If you want to do it on that page without submitting the form you have to use AJAX.

Comment: yes i am i have added a submit button and it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Add a input type `"submit"` in the form.

*Php and html are in the same file that is index.php*, in that case leave the `action = ""` empty:

```
<form method="post" action = "">                
    <select name="q">                
        <option value="DESC" name="DESC">High views</option>    
        <option value="ASC" name="ASC">Low views</option>                   
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">                        
</form>
```

Next thing, change:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

to this:

```
 $q = $_POST['q'];
```

Since you're using the `method = "POST"` in your form, see below:

```
<form method="post" action = "">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are submit from by POST and get data by GET

Try this

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "movie_db";
    $q = $_POST['q'];

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT `title`, `poster`, `descrip`, `movie` ,`Duration`, `views`,`director` FROM `movie_db` ORDER BY `views` ".$q ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<p1>";
     // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        echo " <div class=\"imgc\"><a href=".$row["movie"]."><img src =" . $row["poster"]. "></a></div></p1><p2><b><a href=" .$row["movie"].">" . $row["title"]. "</a></b></p2><br><p3><b>Duration : </b>".$row["Duration"]." Mins</p3> &nbsp; <p3><b> Views : </b> ".$row["views"]."</p3><br><div><p3><b>Description :</b>".$row["descrip"]."</p3></div><br><p5> By ".$row["director"]."</p5><br>";


    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?> 

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the form uses POST whereas you are reading GET in php

Either change

```
<form method="post" action = "">
```

to

```
<form method="get" action = "">
```

Or change this

```
$q = $_POST['q'];
```

to this

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

Comment: Why comma? `DESC` and `ASC` are not columns.